# opengl window freezing during move/resize

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm developing a game using LWJGL. While moving the window, (plan to add resize code in the future), the rendering loop freezes. I would like it to continue running in some fashion while moving. LWJGL does not include glutMainLoop.

The Display belongs to OpenGL, not Java.

Relevant code:

```
    regular = new DisplayMode(800,600);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.47f,0.55f,1.0f, 0.0f); 
    GL11.glClearDepth(1.0f); 
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(regular);
        Display.setTitle("Game Name");
        Display.setIcon(loadIcon("resources/icon.png"));
        Display.create();
        seedresult= new Random(seed);
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
    Display.sync(60);
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //render objects
    Display.update();}
    System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Of course the rendering loop freezes, as the window is processing the move event, so it doesn't render at the same time.

Comment: I was pretty sure that's why, but I'm wondering how I can go about correcting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Try creating the rendering part(Opengl init and update/render) in a separate thread.
I mean create a new thread for you rendering other than using Main thread.

for reference you can check this wiki (last example)
http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Basic_LWJGL_Applet

Comment: I did this and it didn't take long since I already have my main renderer contained in a class, all I had to do was make it a runnable and create a thread in the main function, but this didn't solve it.

Comment: ok last trial...can u place a sleep for minimal amount in the game thread and let me know the status?

Comment: What i'm thinking  is, usually, as the events will be processed - your code is not running until the events are serviced...

Comment: Changing the game to run from within a Canvas has solved the screen freeze issue, but has presented a number of new issues I can work through if I really want it fixed. Apparently, if you have a Canvas in a separate Thread from the Display, it continues to run the game loop during window events. Since my game is multithreaded in every regard other than rendering, I may shelf this if I can effectively get resizing working and a couple other things that make moving the window hard in the first place.

Comment: @Sean:Sorry i didn't get what exactly u mean :( . Can you please let me know the exact changes u made to make it work?

Comment: I created a display Canvas, launched a new thread, and created a Display and set the canvas to parent within the new thread (which also goes on to the render loop).