# Android OpenGL lag every x frame

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developer of Android game.

I have create an GLSurfaceView and draw something in OnDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
like below

```
    void OnDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {
         frame_limit_wait();
         game_logic();
         draw_game();
    }
```

Everything is good, but onething is strange, when drawing n-frame(Occur at GC_EXPLICIT/paused 92ms) will cause game a bit pause, in appplication it's ok, but not in a smooth game.

Original game I was use SurfaceView and Thread update works and smooth.

If add a line below draw_game() like 'system.gc()' it seems work but I feel a bit slow.
Compare to another game engine, my game endinge is running slow.

How to resolve the latency problem ?

Edit : I have solved the issue.
Just initial native Float Buffer once, and use put and position(0) to modify the Buffer content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The garbage collector is running and holding up your frame.  I would recommend taking a close look at the code that executes in the functions frame_limit_wait(), game_logic(), and draw_game() and do everything possible to prevent initializing new objects.

The most common techniques for this include:

- use fields instead of local variables
- use for(int i; i < x; i++) instead of for(variable : list)
- making sure no extra processing is done while drawing frames.

If that still doesn't work then you can try offloading some processing to a separate thread or consider using the NDK and writing native code.  With C++ you don't have to worry about the GC at all.  However both of these methods will complicate your code quite a bit.

Comment: This is so fool question : How do I rendering the draw_game() in seprrate thread ? use getGL() ?

Comment: @ohdroid : for that check this post i made...even though its different platform, it will give you an idea... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730513/opengl-window-freezing-during-move-resize/7730866#7730866

Comment: @Ayyappa : I found this [link]http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg49622.html[/link] very similar my problem...but not work above os 2.1 ...

Comment: @Ayyappa : sorry, please try this http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9300b9d3017e8a23?hl=en&pli=1

Comment: @spatulamania: I have check out my program just ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(coordBuffer.length * 4); cause much GC at runtime, if I remove it, no more GC generate.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your game_logic(),draw_game() code in a separate thread so that when its waiting  in frame_limit_wait() , GC can be serviced in a better way.

I mean instead of using the main thread try running your rendering/update code in seperate thread.

Comment: Actually to say, I don't care GC, but I care about delay, thanks!

Comment: I found the gc have been appear of old SurfaceView, but work fine, no lag; When I changed to GLSurfaceView, it's sensetive on GC pause.